# No module named 'moveit_ros_planning_interface'

Tags: ros2, moveit

Environment Information:

- ROS 2 Distribution: Humble
- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
- Python Version: 3.10.12

MoveIt Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-moveit
```

Code Snippet (filename: server_node.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from moveit_msgs.srv import GetPositionIK
from moveit_msgs.msg import PositionIKRequest, RobotTrajectory
from trajectory_msgs.msg import JointTrajectory, JointTrajectoryPoint
from moveit_msgs.msg import MoveItErrorCodes
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from moveit_ros_planning_interface import MoveGroupInterface
from moveit_ros_planning_interface import PlanningSceneInterface
from moveit_ros_planning_interface import RobotCommander
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/palletizer/src/my_palletizer/my_palletizer/server_node.py", line 10, in <module>
    from moveit_ros_planning_interface import MoveGroupInterface
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moveit_ros_planning_interface'
```

Workspace Structure:

```
/palletizer
|-- build
|-- install
|-- log
|-- src
    |-- moveit
    |-- my_palletizer
        |-- my_palletizer
            |-- build
            |-- __init__.py
            |-- log
            |-- server_node.py
            |-- CMakeLists.txt
            |-- install
            |-- publisher_node.py
            |-- subscriber_node.py
            |-- package.xml
            |-- resource
            |-- setup.cfg
            |-- setup.py
            |-- test
```

Steps Taken for Debugging:

- Installed MoveIt using the provided command.
- Verified the presence of MoveIt in the ROS 2 workspace.

Specific Questions:

1. How can I resolve the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moveit_ros_planning_interface'` issue?
2. Are there additional dependencies or configurations needed for MoveIt in ROS 2 Humble?
3. Is there an alternative way to `import moveit_ros_planning_interface` in ROS 2 Humble?

Any guidance or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

> from moveit_ros_planning_interface import MoveGroupInterface

You are using MoveIt 1 on ROS 2. The MoveIt 2 has been rewritten for ROS 2, and the Python library has been renamed MoveItPy.

##### Documentation

1. Documentation: Please check the official [Motion Planning Python API](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/motion_planning_python_api/motion_planning_python_api_tutorial.html) page.
2. Sample Code: Please check the [ros-planning/moveit2_tutorials](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2_tutorials/blob/ca02877e650659f9dc941697f88e75623cc32137/doc/examples/motion_planning_python_api/scripts/motion_planning_python_api_tutorial.py) repository.

##### Installation

From ROS Iron onwards, you can install it directly from `apt` using the following command:

```
sudo apt install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-moveit-py
```

For ROS Humble, you can compile the main branch of [ros-planning/moveit2](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2). Please feel free to share if there is any issues in source installation.

##### Verification

After successful installation, you should be able to `import MoveItPy` as shown below:

```
$ source /opt/ros/iron/setup.bash
$ python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from moveit.core.robot_state import RobotState
>>> from moveit.planning import MoveItPy, MultiPipelinePlanRequestParameters
>>> 
>>> exit()
```